# How to fix below marathon authentication error

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere, mesos-chronos

I have set 3 node mesos cluster using : [How To Configure a Production-Ready Mesosphere Cluster on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04) (edited)

Next step is to Authenticate Marathon. For that I am using :
[Framework Authentication](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/framework-authentication.html)

Just wanted to know am I using the correct URL or do I need to configure anything before using that url? (edited)

```
--acls=file:///tmp/mesos/config/acls
--credentials=file:///tmp/mesos/config/credentials . I have added those lines mesos.service(/etc/systemd/system/multiuser.targets/mesos-master.service) & to started mesos-master service(systemctl start mesos-master)
added  --mesos_authentication
--mesos_authentication_principal marathon
--mesos_authentication_secret_file /tmp/mesos/config/marathon.secret
--mesos_role marathon     lines in  marathon.service(/etc/systemd/system/multiuser.targets/marathon.service) & to started marathon service(systemctl start marathon)
```

But Marathon is not getting authenticated. Did i miss any step/configuration

Comment: can anyone help me on this

Comment: Can you attach logs from mesos and marathon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to authenticate Marathon framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57051225/how-to-authenticate-marathon-framework)